# How to add a header to each page in a pdf created by wickedpdf using pdf_from_string

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am working with a full stack rails app, trying to add a header to each page that is "printed". The pdf is generated by creating a string using PdfController.renderer.render and passing it the template for the html page, that is then passed to wickedpdf's pdf_from_string method. I have tried styling the header using the print media query, which doesn't seem to get hit when the pdf is generated since it technically isn't being "printed" (I think?)

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: I have a lot of experience with wicked_pdf. Could you please post some code of what you are describing? Are you passing complete HTML documents to the header (including doctype/head/body? You might try setting background colors and tweaking the margin/padding options to 0 to start. Sometimes the default margin and padding make it look like the header isn't there, but it's just covered by the margin, or padded out of the visible "header" area.

Comment: Also, some system packages that install `wkhtmltopdf` use a version that isn't built with `QT`, and isn't capable of some advanced features, like headers and footers. How are you installing `wkhtmltopdf` on your systems?

Comment: Also try using the `print_media_type: true` option to use the print stylesheet, by default `wkhtmltopdf` uses the screen media type.

Comment: @Unixmonkey I'm not sure if I can post a code snippet since this is for my job lol but to try and be more specific, I have added a div into the body of html that is passed to wickedpdf, and would like that div to appear at the top of each page that is created. I tried styling with position: fixed and top: 0, and this DOES get applied and I can see it when I use the media screen query (which makes sense since you say it uses that by default), however it doesn't repeat on each page, only the first

Answer (score 0):

As described in the wicked_pdf README-file it goes like this:

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
  render_to_string('templates/full_pdf_template'),
  header: {
    content: my_header_html_as_string
  }
)
```